# Elasticsearch server stops answering

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, server

I have a problem with elasticsearch server which is deployed locally. 
In most cases it works as expected, but in rare cases this happens:

- Server starts and begins creating indices as expected
- But after some short time server just "dissapears" and stops answering
- I recieve this kind of exception on client side

  `Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.. Call: Status code unknown from: PUT /0bf1e0a7057f4ed2aefd86ee3908dd28_15 ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`
- And there is nothing in server log (no messages like "closing...", "stopping..." or something like this)

Do you have any ideas what could cause such behavior?

P.S. It is hard to reproduce this problem, that's why all I've got is logs.

Comment: It's difficult to say what's causing this behavior on your side. It could be caused by not-closed connections in your code, or because ES ran out of memory. Try to check your cluster's health with the Health API when it 'disappears' https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html

Comment: @KevinQuinzel is it possible for ES to run out of memory on x64?

Comment: By "not-closed connections" do you mean connections that were opened from client side?

Comment: Well, I'm talking about the heap size. The one that can be customized in the jmv.options file. By default it uses 2GB. when reaching those limits, Java runs out of memory, causing an unresponsive cluster. I just wanted to make sure that you were not running out of this memory :D  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html

Comment: And yeah, I was thinking about opened connections from the client side. I'm not sure about this last part because I'm more familiar with the Python client :( But hopefully, as a Xmass miracle, an ES C# user will come to the rescue :) For now, let's discard that the issue is caused by insufficient memory

Comment: I am running into similar issues. Hoping to get insights into this from people who might have encountered this.